# How do you understand Hex file ? (Extended Address Record)

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, bootloader

I am trying to make a bootloader for PIC18 so I need to understand how to process a hex file correctly. For example I understand what to do with the following hex line.

```
:040C0000E2EFFFF030
```

`04`: number of bytes

`0C00` : Address of hex digits

`00`: Data records

`E2EFFFF0`: Sequence of data

`30`: Checksum

so I would know what to do with the above line, but how about the following hex line.

```
:020000040001F9
```

`02` : # of bytes

`0000`: Address

`04`:  Extended Linear Address Record

`0001`: data

`F9`: Checksum

But what exactly do I do with it?  Am I writing those data to that address? Can you translate it to machine language?

By the way my application program starts at address `0c00` and bootloader starts at address `0020`, and above it, is the interrupt vector. Thanks!

**Update**

If the third line of hex file was the following, would the address `FFC0` change ?

```
:10FFC000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF000001E9EF5E
```

I am thinking since the second line of hex file has `04` (Extended Linear Address Record), then I should add `0001` to the address of the third line `FFC0`, so the new address would be like this.

`$0001 + $FFC0`will equal `1FFC0` , so the next set of data bytes from line 3 should be written to this address `1FFC0`, is this correct ?

Comment: Right now, this is someone's hexual phantasy.

Comment: It's only a hexual fantasy because it is a PIC18.  After you are married it is a check sum.

Comment: Please check the new update with my new assumption, thanks!

Comment: Yes. That is correct. And prepend every address with $0001 until you see another 04 line to change it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From wikipedia [Intel Hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) (the obvious source for such informations)

> 04, Extended Linear Address Record, allowing for fully 32 bit
>   addressing (up to 4GiB). The address field is 0000, the byte count is
>   02. The two data bytes (two hex digit pairs in big endian order) represent the upper 16 bits of the 32 bit address for all subsequent
>   00 type records until the next 04 type record comes. If there is not a
>   04 type record, the upper 16 bits default to 0000. To get the absolute
>   address for subsequent 00 type records, the address specified by the
>   data field of the most recent 04 record is added to the 00 record
>   addresses.

So the formula is `(linAddr <<16) + addr` or in your case ($0001 << 16) + $FFC0

And for the case of 02/Extended Segment Address Record, the formula changed to
`(segAddr << 4) + addr`